# Monte Carlo Simulation - efficient simulation of tail outcomes

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, simulation

When running Monte Carlo type simulations in situations where you're only interested in tail outcomes, do you know of a way to only simulate those outcomes, so that you can come up with more reliable answers in fewer simulations.

Comment: "Importance Sampling" is the keyword you are looking for. For a start you might look in Paul Glasserman's book on Monte Carlo Methods for Financial Engineering.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Stephan! I am not very good at this kind of mathematics. Can you explain be the concept in layman terms? An example, maybe? TIA!

Comment: Sorry, but this is really not the site for layman's term questions, it is a site for questions people have that do math for a living. Moreover a quick google search should be enough to give you some ideas.

Comment: Okay, apologies! Thanks for taking time out.